# Как изменять значения через чекбоксы в Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Я только начал изучать библиотеку Tkinter, да и Python в целом. Хочу сделать так, чтобы при активации одного чекбокса изменялось соответствующее значение в словаре. Я не совсем понимаю, как нужно вернуть значения чекбокса... Для примера я хочу добиться типа такого результата:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
preset_configs = {
    "test1": "0",
    "test2": "0",

}


def on_click(toggle, key_set):
    if toggle.get() == 1:
        preset_configs[key_set] = "1"
    else:
        preset_configs[key_set] = "0"

check_var = IntVar()
check_var1 = IntVar()
check = Checkbutton(root, text='Текст1', onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable=check_var, command=on_click(check_var, "test1"))
check1 = Checkbutton(root, text='Текст2', onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable=check_var1, command=on_click(check_var1, "test2"))
check.pack()
check1.pack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В параметре `command` вы передали не функцию, а результат ее выполнения. Для того, чтобы таким образом вызвать функцию с параметрами нужно использовать `lambda`-функцию.

Замените

```
check = Checkbutton(root, text='Текст1', onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable=check_var, command=on_click(check_var, "test1"))
check1 = Checkbutton(root, text='Текст2', onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable=check_var1, command=on_click(check_var1, "test2"))
```

На

```
check = Checkbutton(root, text='Текст1', onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable=check_var, command=lambda: on_click(check_var, "test1"))
check1 = Checkbutton(root, text='Текст2', onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable=check_var1, command=lambda: on_click(check_var1, "test2")
```

Comment: Я видел уже подобное решение, когда гуглил пример, чтобы решить эту проблему, но не понимал, что она конкретно делает. Теперь буду знать. Спасибо, всё заработало!